# MySQL returning results from a column with different statuses

Tags: mysql, select

I want to find all order_id and product_id from order_details table, where status_order from orders table does not contain "O", "E", "P" ...

```
SELECT `order_id`, `product_id`
FROM `order_details`
WHERE `order_id`
NOT IN (SELECT `order_id` FROM `orders`
        WHERE 
        `status`="O" OR
        `status`="E" OR
        `status`="P" OR
        `status`="F" OR
        `status`="I" OR
        `status`="Y" OR
        `status`="B" OR
        `status`="J" OR
        `status`="H" OR
        `status`="G" OR
        `status`="D")
```

Comment: what is your status column contains, provide samples of current data?

Answer (score 1):

```
select od.order_id ,od.product_id
from order_details od
inner join orders os
on od.order_id = os.order_id
where os.status_order not in ('o','e','p')
```

Comment: I have received this Column 'order_id' in field list is ambiguous